# mysql select procedure

Tags: mysql

Это код процедуры

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE select_from_users_by_user(
IN p_user VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN 
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user=p_user;
END #
```

А это код в php

```
$query = "CALL select_from_users_by_user('".$_SESSION['user']."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result) die("error to connect date base: ".mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Но не работает, выдает ошибку контекста. От чего это может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, не знаю. INT значения у меня через PHP сразу в CALL нормально всё закидывало. Правда с varchar не пробовал. Ради этого специально даже в исходниках своих покапался где встретился вот такой код. Где уже в хранимой процедуре висят все проверки. Если $_GET['id_tt'] не инт, то exception вылетит и на попытке её вывзвать

```
  $db->query ("CALL AddVariant (".$_GET['id_tt'].")");
```

Comment: Ну так в вопросе речь идет о процедуре возвращающей дескриптор с табличным результатом...

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно передаете параметры в вашу процедуру.. В качестве параметра нужно передавать переменную а не строку..

```
mysql> SET @user = "vasea";
mysql> CALL select_from_users_by_user(@user);
```

надеюсь идея понятна..

Comment: так тоже не работает :)

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема PHP... Не лечиться...